# Adding labels to a data set generated by itertools.product

Tags: python-2.7, iterator, iteration

I am using the python 2.7 iter.product to generate the Cartesian product of three data-sets.

This is the same as three nested loops.  However before entering the  loop I want to print label "Fruit Type:" and  "Tree Type:" If thats not clear Ive put an example of the output I want below.

What is the pythonic way to do that, I could generate the Cartesian. product of the sets and then add the labels  in post processing but doesnt that defeat the purpose of using itertools to reduce the memory footprint?

## Code sample

```
import itertools

FRUITS=['apple','orange','pear']
TREES=['ash','oak','beech']
ANIMALS=['dog','cat','horse']


def foo(a,b,c):
  print "fruit is " + str(a) + ", tree is " + str(b) + ", animal is " +  str(c)

[ foo(a,b,c) for a, b, c in itertools.product(FRUITS, TREES, ANIMALS)]
```

## Output wanted

```
***************************************
Fruit Type: apple
***************************************
---------------------------------------
Tree Type: ash
---------------------------------------
fruit is apple, tree is ash, animal is dog
fruit is apple, tree is ash, animal is cat
fruit is apple, tree is ash, animal is horse
---------------------------------------
Tree Type: oak
---------------------------------------
fruit is apple, tree is oak, animal is dog
fruit is apple, tree is oak, animal is cat
fruit is apple, tree is oak, animal is horse
---------------------------------------
Tree Type: beech
---------------------------------------
fruit is apple, tree is beech, animal is dog
fruit is apple, tree is beech, animal is cat
fruit is apple, tree is beech, animal is horse
---------------------------------------
Tree Type: ash
---------------------------------------
***************************************
Fruit Type: orange
***************************************
---------------------------------------
Tree Type: ash
---------------------------------------

fruit is orange, tree is ash, animal is dog
fruit is orange, tree is ash, animal is cat
fruit is orange, tree is ash, animal is horse
---------------------------------------
Tree Type: oak
---------------------------------------
fruit is orange, tree is oak, animal is dog
fruit is orange, tree is oak, animal is cat
fruit is orange, tree is oak, animal is horse
---------------------------------------
Tree Type: beech
---------------------------------------
fruit is orange, tree is beech, animal is dog
fruit is orange, tree is beech, animal is cat
fruit is orange, tree is beech, animal is horse
***************************************
Fruit Type: pear
***************************************
---------------------------------------
Tree Type: ash
---------------------------------------

fruit is pear, tree is ash, animal is dog
fruit is pear, tree is ash, animal is cat
fruit is pear, tree is ash, animal is horse
---------------------------------------
Tree Type: oak
---------------------------------------
fruit is pear, tree is oak, animal is dog
fruit is pear, tree is oak, animal is cat
fruit is pear, tree is oak, animal is horse
---------------------------------------
Tree Type: beech
---------------------------------------
fruit is pear, tree is beech, animal is dog
fruit is pear, tree is beech, animal is cat
fruit is pear, tree is beech, animal is horse
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is a way:

```
from itertools import product

FRUITS = ['apple', 'orange', 'pear']
TREES = ['ash', 'oak', 'beech']
ANIMALS = ['dog', 'cat', 'horse']

lst = [(fruit, tree, animal) for fruit, tree in product(FRUITS, TREES)
       for animal in ANIMALS]

fmt = 'fruit is {} tree {} is animal is {}'
last_tree_type = None
last_fruit_type = None
for item in lst:
    if last_fruit_type != item[0]:
        last_fruit_type = item[0]
        print(20*'=')
        print('fruit type: {}'.format(item[0]))
        print(20*'=')
    if last_tree_type != item[1]:
        last_tree_type = item[1]
        print(20*'-')
        print('tree type: {}'.format(item[1]))
        print(20*'-')
    print(fmt.format(*item))
```

`lst` contains the triplets `[('apple', 'ash', 'dog'), ('apple', 'ash', 'cat'), ...]`; the rest is just the formatting for the string.

it is usually good advice to collect your 'data' first and do string formatting as late as possible.